# Python selenium: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1 keeps on popping up

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

Does anybody have the solution yet? The script was working perfectly fine until yesterday, but suddenly it stopped working. Don't know why.. :(

I tried searching the answer all over Google, but didn't find yet.
Tried adding options.add_argument('--log-level=3') as well, but no luck.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score -1):

What is going on here?  I've had this issue before and my solution was to uninstall and reinstall chrome and it worked fine.  But now, even uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't work and this 'Devtools listening...' line is popping up right away and my script doesn't work!

Everyone seems to have the same experience with this message.  It's working fine for the longest time and then all of a sudden this message pops up and the script stops working?  Chrome has to be caching something somewhere.

Answer (score -3):

Simple problem, simple solution :
after

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

you clean the screen :

```
    print("\n" * 100)
```

Comment: Wow. Seriously? Hide it instead of disabling it?